# How do you create strongly typed redux middleware in TypeScript from Redux's type definitions?

Tags: typescript, redux

I have a TypeScript project that uses React and Redux and I'm trying to add some middleware functions.  I got started by implementing one from Redux's samples like so:

```
// ---- middleware.ts ----
export type MiddlewareFunction = (store: any) => (next: any) => (action: any) => any;

export class MyMiddleWare {
    public static Logger: MiddlewareFunction = store => next => action => {
        // Do stuff
        return next(action);
    }
}

// ---- main.ts ---- 
import * as MyMiddleware from "./middleware";

const createStoreWithMiddleware = Redux.applyMiddleware(MyMiddleWare.Logger)(Redux.createStore);
```

The above works just fine but since this is TypeScript I'd like to make it strongly-typed, ideally using the types defined by Redux so I don't have to reinvent and maintain my own.  So, here are the relevant excerpts from my index.d.ts file for Redux:

```
// ---- index.d.ts from Redux ----
export interface Action {
    type: any;
}

export interface Dispatch<S> {
    <A extends Action>(action: A): A;
}

export interface MiddlewareAPI<S> {
    dispatch: Dispatch<S>;
    getState(): S;
}

export interface Middleware {
    <S>(api: MiddlewareAPI<S>): (next: Dispatch<S>) => Dispatch<S>;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to bring those types into my Logger method but I'm not having much luck.  It seems to me that something like this ought to work:

```
interface MyStore {
    thing: string;
    item: number;
}

interface MyAction extends Action {
    note: string;
}

export class MyMiddleWare {
    public static Logger: Middleware = (api: MiddlewareAPI<MyStore>) => (next: Dispatch<MyStore>) => (action: MyAction) => {
        const currentState: MyStore = api.getState();
        const newNote: string = action.note;
        // Do stuff
        return next(action);
    };
}
```

but instead I get this error:

*Error TS2322: Type '(api: MiddlewareAPI) => (next: Dispatch) => (action: Action) => Action' is not assignable to type 'Middleware'.

  Types of parameters 'api' and 'api' are incompatible.

    Type 'MiddlewareAPI' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareAPI'.

      Type 'S' is not assignable to type 'MyStore'.*

I see the <S> generic declared in the type definition, but I've tried a lot of different combinations and I can't seem to figure out how to specify it as MyStore so that it is recognized as the generic type in the rest of the declarations.  For example, according to the declaration api.getState() should return a MyStore object.  Same thinking applies to the action type <A>, of course.

Comment: Did you by any chance find a good solution? Using class not a function?

Answer (score 25):

MyStore is not required.

```
export const Logger: Middleware =
  (api: MiddlewareAPI<void>) => 
  (next: Dispatch<void>) => 
  <A extends Action>(action: A) => {
    // Do stuff
   return next(action);
  };
```

or

```
export const Logger: Middleware = api => next => action => {
  // Do stuff
  return next(action);
};
```

Have a Nice Dev

Comment: Neither of these answer the question (which I'll update to clarify) because calls to api.getState() do not return a strongly-typed object.  The point of all this is to get the complier to follow the type declarations as they are defined so you don't have to do any extra casting.

For the first one you have to do this:
const currentState: MyStore = api.getState() as any as MyStore;

For the second one you still have to do this:
const currentState: MyStore = api.getState() as MyStore;

Comment: @BernardHymmen did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @NSjonas - Sorry about not replying earlier.  A colleague of mine pointed out that the type definitions made it structurally impossible to create strongly typed middleware in a direct way.  The best you can do is implement some kind of work around like what Martin Backschat suggested.  That's essentially what I ended up doing, though I didn't know about creating type guards using "is" at the time so my solution wasn't as nice as Martin's.  
FWIW: It looks like people have been working on this problem (https://github.com/reactjs/redux/pull/2563) but I haven't tried those changes yet.

Comment: Not sure if the type definitions changed since november 2017, but it is (now?) possible to get a typed object back from store.getState().

The MiddlewareAPI interface looks like this:
interface MiddlewareAPI<D extends Dispatch = Dispatch, S = any> {
  dispatch: D
  getState(): S
}

So passing your app's state as the 2nd generic will result in a typed state from store.getState().

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

First is the middleware creator that accepts a todo function as input which is run as core logic for the middleware. The todo function accepts an object that encapsulates `store(MiddlewareAPI<S>)`, `next(Dispatch<S>)`, `action(Action<S>)` as well as any other your custimized parameters.
Please be aware that I use `as Middleware` to force the middleware creator to return a Middleware. This is the magic I use to get rid of the trouble.

```
import { MiddlewareAPI, Dispatch, Middleware } from 'redux';
import { Action } from 'redux-actions';

export interface MiddlewareTodoParams<S> {
  store: MiddlewareAPI<S>;
  next: Dispatch<S>;
  action: Action<S>;
  [otherProperty: string]: {};
}

export interface MiddlewareTodo<S> {
  (params: MiddlewareTodoParams<S>): Action<S>;
}

// <S>(api: MiddlewareAPI<S>): (next: Dispatch<S>) => Dispatch<S>;
export const createMiddleware = <S>(
  todo: MiddlewareTodo<S>,
  ...args: {}[]
): Middleware => {
  return ((store: MiddlewareAPI<S>) => {
    return (next: Dispatch<S>) => {
      return action => {
        console.log(store.getState(), action.type);
        return todo({ store, next, action, ...args });
      };
    };
  // Use as Middleware to force the result to be Middleware
  }) as Middleware;
};
```

Second part is the definition of my todo function. In this example I write some token into cookie. It is just a POC for Middleware so I don't care about the XSS risk in my codes at all.

```
export type OAUTH2Token = {
  header: {
    alg: string;
    typ: string;
  };
  payload?: {
    sub: string;
    name: string;
    admin: boolean;
  };
};


export const saveToken2Cookie: MiddlewareTodo<OAUTH2Token> = params => {
  const { action, next } = params;
  if (action.type === AUTH_UPDATE_COOKIE && action.payload !== undefined) {
    cookie_set('token', JSON.stringify(action.payload));
  }
  return next(action);
};
```

Lastly, here is what it looks of my store configruation.

```
const store: Store<{}> = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  // applyMiddleware(thunk, oauth2TokenMiddleware(fetch))
  applyMiddleware(thunk, createMiddleware<OAUTH2Token>(saveToken2Cookie))
);
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution that goes like this:

```
export type StateType = { thing: string, item: number };

export type ActionType =
    { type: "MY_ACTION", note: string } |
    { type: "PUSH_ACTIVITIY", activity: string };

// Force cast of generic S to my StateType
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
function isApi<M>(m: any): m is MiddlewareAPI<StateType> {
    return true;
}

export type MiddlewareFunction =
    (api: MiddlewareAPI<StateType>, next: (action: ActionType) => ActionType, action: ActionType) => ActionType;

export function handleAction(f: MiddlewareFunction): Middleware {
    return <S>(api: MiddlewareAPI<S>) => next => action => {
        if (isApi(api)) {
            // Force cast of generic A to my ActionType
            const _action = (<ActionType>action);
            const _next: (action: ActionType) => ActionType = a => {
                // Force cast my ActionType to generic A
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
                return next(<any>a);
            };
            // Force cast my ActionType to generic A
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
            return f(api, _next, _action) as any;
        } else {
            return next(action);
        }
    };
}
```

With the `handeAction` function I can now define middlewares:

```
// Log actions and state.thing before and after action dispatching
export function loggingMiddleware(): Middleware {
    return handleAction((api, next, action) => {
        console.log(" \nBEGIN ACTION DISPATCHING:");
        console.log(`----- Action:    ${JSON.stringify(action)}\n`);
        const oldState = api.getState();

        const retVal = next(action);

        console.log(` \n----- Old thing: ${oldState.thing}`);
        console.log(`----- New thing: ${api.getState().thing)}\n`);
        console.log("END ACTION DISPATCHING\n");

        return retVal;
    });
}

// Another middleware...
export interface DataHub = { ... }:
export function dataHandlingMiddleware(datahub: DataHub): Middleware {
    return handleAction((api, next, action) => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case "PUSH_ACTIVITY": {
                handlePushActivities(action.activity, api, /* outer parameter */ datahub);
                break;
            }
            default:
        }
        return next(action);
    });
}
```

Please note that the middlewares can also require additional parameters like services etc (here: DataHub), that are passed in during setup.
The store setup looks like this:

```
import {
    Store, applyMiddleware, StoreCreator, StoreEnhancer,
    createStore, combineReducers, Middleware, MiddlewareAPI
} from "redux";

const middlewares = [
    dataHandlingMiddleware(datahub),
    loggingMiddleware()];

const rootReducer = combineReducers<StateType>({ ... });
const initialState: StateType = {};

// Trick to enable Redux DevTools with TS: see https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-ts
const devTool = (f: StoreCreator) => {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
    return ((window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__) ? (window as any).__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ : f;
};
const middleware: StoreEnhancer<StateType> = applyMiddleware(...middlewares);
const store: Store<StateType> = middleware(devTool(createStore))(rootReducer, initialState);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Middleware type which saves you from having to annotate the curried functions:

```
import type { Dispatch, AnyAction } from 'redux'

export interface MiddlewareAPI<S, E extends AnyAction> {
  dispatch: Dispatch<E>
  getState(): S
}

export type Middleware<S, E extends AnyAction> =
  (api: MiddlewareAPI<S, E>) =>
  (next: Dispatch<E>) =>
  (event: E) => ReturnType<Dispatch<E>>

const middleware: Middleware<MyStore, MyEvent> = (api) => (next) => (event) => {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: This gives me: `Type 'Dispatch<E>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Dispatch<AnyAction>'.
  Type 'AnyAction' is not assignable to type 'E'.
    'AnyAction' is assignable to the constraint of type 'E', but 'E' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'AnyAction'.ts(2344)`

Comment: @Tom, thanks, I have fixed it. The previous version probably stopped working on a typescript update.

Answer (score 0):

I just Passed through the same problem as you!

Solved it by putting the last function between parenthesis and then forcing it's type to be `Dispatch<EffectAction>`

```
interface EffectAction extends Action {
  effect<T> (action: T): void
}

const effects: Middleware = (api: MiddlewareAPI<any>) => (next: Dispatch<EffectAction>) => ((action: EffectAction) => {
  if (action.effect instanceof Function) action.effect(action)
  return next(action)
}) as Dispatch<EffectAction>
```